# Selenium can't find a CSS selector

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Selenium catches a *NoSuchElementException* after retrieving exactly 9 entries from the website. I think the problem might be in that the page contents doesn't have enough time to load, but I'm not sure.

I've written the code following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIcfhlpq_xc&t=1248s) (nineteenths minute).

```
import requests
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

URL = 'https://www.alibaba.com//trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=white+hoodie'
time.sleep(1)

driver.get(URL)

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
time.sleep(2)

items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.J-offer-wrapper')

num = 1
for i in items:
    print(num)
    product_name = i.find_element_by_css_selector('h4').text
    price = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.elements-offer-price-normal').text
    time.sleep(0.5)
    num += 1
    print(price, product_name)


#driver.close()
```

If you have a clue why Selenium stops at the 10th entry and how to overcome this issue, please, share.

Comment: Thats because the 10th element,20th,30th etc... are "Ads" that have no price. https://imgur.com/a/ExoFNVA. Better skip it somehow with a  try:
        price = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.elements-offer-price-normal').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that because the 10th item is not like the rest. It's an ad thingy and not a hoodie as you've searched for. I suspect you'd want to exclude this so you are left only with the results you are actually interested in.

All you need to do is change the way you identify `items` (this just one of the options):

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.img-switcher-parent')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update for the error handling as below:

```
    for i in items:

        print(num)
        try:
            product_name = i.find_element_by_css_selector('h4').text
        except:
            product_name=''
        try:
            price = i.find_element_by_css_selector('.elements-offer-pricenormal').text
        except:
            price=''
        time.sleep(0.5)
        num += 1
        print(price, product_name)
```